# How to creating dialog in running game android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a game with fallow code

In implement runnable

While playing
Update
Control
Draw

I wont to create dialog on control and dialog create once 
game paused if out of dialog touched or back key pressed dialog close and game resume running  .

I'm new in android programming

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
Boolean b 
If(b){
handler{
New runnable{
// my dialog
}
}b=false;
}
```

If any body know beter way pls tell me